# How to dynamically add input fields based on json data in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My jsfiddle is

https://jsfiddle.net/ahnu5zz9/

My json data is

```
    [{
    "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fab",
    "refId": 7929,
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Indian Act 1931",
    "__v": 0,
    "feilds": [{
        "refId": 7912,
        "name": "arms(if any)",
        "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fac",
        "sections": [],
        "subFeilds": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb6",
    "refId": 7930,
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Narcotic",
    "__v": 0,
    "feilds": [{
        "refId": 7913,
        "name": "qty",
        "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb7",
        "sections": [],
        "subFeilds": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbbf",
    "refId": 7933,
    "type": "option",
    "text": "Ker",
    "__v": 0,
    "feilds": [{
        "refId": 7918,
        "name": "wild",
        "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc2",
        "sections": ["sec1", "sec2"],
        "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 17890,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc4"
        }, {
            "refId": 7891,
            "name": "item",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc3"
        }]
    }, {
        "refId": 7919,
        "name": "enc",
        "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc0",
        "sections": ["sec2"],
        "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 7892,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc1"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

First I need to show options as

```
<div id="add">
<div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
 <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.name" name="type" >
 <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
 <option v-for="post in data" v-bind:value="post.refId" >{{post.text}}</option>  
</div>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

After My first selection, is there any way to divide input field into components in vue js and call components based on the selection?

So, when I select 1st option indian act,1931, an input field comes there arms(if any). So in that case i need my v-model as bok.data[0].head.arms(if any). in next case when I select option 2. field with qty comes, so i need to send data as bok.data[0].head.qty.

In the 3rd case 1 select ker, both wild and enc comes as dropdown. On clicking this another input field comes. When I click wild, qty and item comes. So, I need to send this values as bok.data[0].value.qty and bok.data[0].value.item.

Also, I need to have multiple select options possible for wild and enc. I can able to select both wild and enc using multiple="".

How can I able to achieve the above result? I looked in several tutorials but none providing an answer. I am a beginner in coding and don't have much idea.

Comment: You canno't use bok.name cause name is in other object 'feilds', so you have to use another v-for = "feild bok.feilds"  <==> feild.name

Comment: hello @Mgasmi plz help me to have a solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahnu5zz9/ my fiddle.. plz check